# Allow anyone to see how a different hat will look on someone else's profile

Tags: feature-request, winter-bash

In Winter Bash people can wear their hats, so anyone who visits their profile can see it overlaid on their profile picture. That is nice, but I sometimes I would like to see how a different hat a user has earned will look on their profile. This is the reason I am asking to have the option of seeing how a different hat will look on someone.

- This will change **not** change the hat for everyone, only you.
- The change will be temporary and will be cleared after a reload.

Comment: They could make it so that we see other's hats just like our own hats, but without the "wear hat" button. For example, [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFtHs.png) is how my hats could look for other users. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOfL1.png) is how others' hats currently look.

Comment: Why would you want to see what another user's hat would look like?

Comment: What exactly is the point of this, why is it worth implementing for just a few weeks each year on a non-essential component, and why would it be put above the myriad feature requests that have been waiting 5-7 weeks already?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a workaround for testing your hats on somebody else avatar.

1. Go to your *Winter Bash* profile URL where you can see all your hats, e.g.
   https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=profile#winter-bash
2. Change your avatar to somebody else by replacing relevant HTML tag.

   This can be achieved by [opening *DevTools*](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/shortcuts) console and running the following JS command:

   ```
    $x('//a[@class="wb-hat-details-avatar"]/img')[0].src = "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/URL_TO_YOUR_AVATAR"
   ```

   <sup>Note: Replace URL with the avatar of another user.</sup>

Then you can basically see how different user would look like having your hats.

Comment: The Javascript command doesn't work for me but you can also right click on the image, inspect and change the SRC attribute: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cleCz.png

Comment: that way you can only use the hats **you** own, but still the only workaround right now